# Trying to change the word 'category' to 'client' in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to change the word "category" to the word "client" and "categories" to "clients" on my wordpress site. I would like the change to work in the dashboard, as well as on the categories page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information about taxonomies is stored in the global `$wp_taxonomies` array.

Since it is a simple array of objects, we can modify it and see what happens. The properties we are interested in are `Clients` and `Client`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'Clients_init');
function Clients_init()
{
    global $wp_taxonomies;

    $wp_taxonomies['category']->labels = (object)array(
        'name' => 'Clients',
        'menu_name' => 'Clients',
        'singular_name' => 'Client',
        'search_items' => 'Search Clients',
        'popular_items' => 'Popular Clients',
        'all_items' => 'All Clients',
        'parent_item' => null, // Tags aren't hierarchical
        'parent_item_colon' => null,
        'edit_item' => 'Edit Client',
        'update_item' => 'Update Client',
        'add_new_item' => 'Add new Client',
        'new_item_name' => 'New Client Name',
        'separate_items_with_commas' => 'Separata Clients with commas',
        'add_or_remove_items' => 'Add or remove Clients',
        'choose_from_most_used' => 'Choose from the most used Clients',
    );

    $wp_taxonomies['category']->label = 'Clients';
}
```

Would you please add above code in your current theme `function.php` and check it?

Comment: Thanks a ton! Worked like a charm! I had something similar but I think my syntax was wrong. Thanks again!